# Nginx copy location path to proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

In nginx i wish to do the copy the location path to the proxy_pass, but i don't want to copy full path.

If the url is https://127.0.0.1/path1/name1, i just want to copy the `path1`

Like following:

```
location ^~ /path1/{
    --some if else statement--
    proxy_pass https://backend/path1/;
}
```

I tried to use `$request_uri` but it will show `/path1/name1` too

Answer (score 0):

Just use `rewrite` directive, as shown in [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass).

> When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the `rewrite` directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (`break`):
>
> [...]
>
> In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.

So this is it:

```
location ^~ /path1/ {
    rewrite ^ /path1/ break;
    proxy_pass https://backend;
}
```

Comment: is there another way using regex other than hardcoded `path1`?

Comment: Check rewrite directive http://nginx.org/r/rewrite